# modgrammar import lists to use as disjunct literals?

Tags: python-3.x, modgrammar

I'd like to be able to have files that contain lists of terms that I can read and use in a modgrammar grammar, but OR() doesn't work on a Python list as far as I can tell...

```
from modgrammar import *

with open(termfile) as f:
    terms = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

class SomeGrammar(Grammar):
    grammar = (OR(terms))
```

Trying to parse strings that begin with anything but the first term in the list throws an exception.  Is there a way to do this cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modgrammar will interpret a list as a series of terms to match in order, so `OR(terms)` is interpreted as "match these in order OR (nothing else)", which isn't what you're looking for.

Fortunately, Python has a built-in syntax to take a list and pass it as multiple arguments for a function (like OR).  You should be able to use `OR(*terms)` to do what you want instead.